# Updating polygon geometry: deleting inner rings with python

Tags: python, geometry, ogr

I've searched, but can't find clear explanations how can I simply delete inner rings from existing polygons with python or extract outter rings and overwrite the geometry. Seems GDAL/OGR should be the simplest, but still I need some help...

Simple vision of mine would be:

```
dataSrc=driver.Open(shp)
layer=dataSrc.GetLayer()
for i in xrange(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    if geometry.GetArea()<200:
        layer.DeleteFeature(i)
    if geometry.GetGeometryCount()>1:
        geometry=geometry.GetGeometryRef(0) #overwrite geom, getting the first ring outer
        feature.SetGeometry(geometry)
        layer.SetFeature(feature)
```

geometry.Destroy()

This doesn't loop through, it's just how I would like to see.

As I know the first ring or the first part of the geometry should be the outer ring, so I assumed I can just ask for it like that.Suppose that's not a problem.

So, probably the question is just about Updating Geometry. I open dataset withouth specific- Reading or Writing, so I assume it should let me write in it not just read. But if I do not want to have a new dataset, can I just update write like that or i should anywhays better create a new dataset?

Or maybe there is even more simple way to solve this with python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution with arcgisscripting, if anyone gona need to automate it.

It's **really simple**,.. just required some time to catch those holes :)

```
rows=gp.UpdateCursor(shp) #everything is done with one Cursor, but couple of arrays
row=rows.Next()
try:
    while row:
        if row.shape.area < 200:  #it's just deleting small polygons
            rows.DeleteRow(row)
        else:                     #part of cleaning from inner rings (donuts)
            geom=row.shape
            array=geom.GetPart(0)
            pnt=array.Next()
            newarray = gp.CreateObject("Array") #writing geometry to newArray       
            while pnt:
                newarray.add(pnt)
                pnt=array.Next()
                newpnt=newarray.Next()
                if not pnt:                     #this is the HOLE! 
                    break                       #when detect - break the loop!
            row.shape=newarray
            rows.UpdateRow(row)
        row=rows.Next()

    del row
    del rows
except:
    gp.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 2):

The part about deleting the features. Seems it's often not allowed.
Found, there is a possibilty to test it: 
http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRLayer.html#aeedbda1a62f9b89b8e5f24332cf22286

```
layer.TestCapability("DeleteField")
```

and so I get False..

And accessing just the first ring goes well, I've checked with area calculations.

The solution then is just to CREATE a new file with features I need from old file..
Correct me if I am misstaken.

Comment: You are correct. Updatability of layers varies over formats, but creation of a new dataset always works.

Comment: Seems I at such point I am comming back to arcgisscripting..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ArcGIS [Union](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/union.htm) and [Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) tools to fill gaps. Make sure to use the `NO_GAPS` option in the union tool.

```
import arcpy

in_shp = r'C:/path/to/your/shapefile.shp'
out_shp = r'C:/path/to/your/out_shapefile.shp'

arcpy.Union_analysis(in_shp, "in_memory/union", gaps = 'NO_GAPS')
arcpy.Dissolve_management("in_memory/union", out_shp)
```